# How to write a custom tree function to count the number of file

Tags: powershell

If I run `tree /f` in my `PowerShell`, I will get a result like

```
D:.
├─dir1
│  │  file1.avi
│  │  file2.txt
│  │  file3.xml
│  │
│  └─dirdir
│          f.txt
│          m.txt
│
├─dir2
│      testfile1.txt
│
├─dir3
└─dir4
```

But I don't hope to get the file name in the final level, I hope to get the number of the file. I mean this is what I have expected

```
D:.
├─dir1
│  │  3
│  │
│  └─dirdir
│          2
│
├─dir2
│      1
│
├─dir3
└─dir4
```

How to make such function with `Powershell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't be possible without modifying the output.
I did something similar with modifying the output of the pscx cmdlet
[Show-Tree to include LastWriteTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472313/6811411)

But eventually this one liner comes near enaugh:

```
gci D: -R -File|Group Directory | Select Count,Name
```

Sample output from A:

```
Count Name
----- ----
    1 A:\
    1 A:\Processed
    4 A:\temp\rktest
    1 A:\temp\rktest\SubDirL1
    1 A:\temp\rktest\SubDirL1\SubDirL2
```

Or, to have better headings:

```
> gci -R -File|Group Directory|%{[PSCustomObject]@{FileCount=$_.Count;Directory=$_.Name}}

FileCount Directory
--------- ---------
        1 A:\
        1 A:\Processed
        4 A:\temp\rktest
        1 A:\temp\rktest\SubDirL1
        1 A:\temp\rktest\SubDirL1\SubDirL2
```